# Retrieve documentId from future

Tags: function, flutter, future

I have not been able to find an answer to my problem so I will ask here.

I created a document that contains one piece of data. Once that document is created I need to retrieve the id of that document so I can use that string to add to another document that will be created next. The code is below where I call the Future function "saveNewAgency" as well as the code for the Future function.

```
if (globals.newAgency == true) {
      firestoreService.saveNewAgency(newAgency);
      agentProvider.saveAgent();
      globals.newAgency = false;
    } else {
      firestoreService.saveAgency(newAgency);
    }

 Future<String> saveNewAgency(Agency agency) async {
    DocumentReference docRef = await _db
        .collection('agency')
        .add(agency.toMap())
        .then((value) => value.id);

    //globals.agencyId = docRef.id;
  }
```

As you can see I tried to set a global variable inorder to get the documentId but that code never gets executed so I commented it out.

This is a small thing but it is just another step I have reached in my journey of learning flutter and firebase.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String Id = _db  .collection('agency').doc().id;
Future<String> saveNewAgency(Agency agency) async {
    await _db
        .collection('agency')
       .doc(id)
       .set(agency.toMap())
      .then((value) => {
           print(id);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Subair but this code looks like it is saving to an existing document. What I need is to create an agency document and get it's documentId so that I can use it in the next steps.

Comment: I was able to make it work. Thanks both responders.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Future<String> saveNewAgency(Agency agency) async {
    await _db
        .collection('agency')
        .add(agency.toMap())
        .then((value) => {
           globals.agencyId = value.id
      });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This didn't work. value.id is null.